# .gltf model not appearing in the browser

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I have a .gltf file. I can open this with 3d viewer. But, when I try to load this in the browser, it loads (no error in the console),, but it doesn't show up in the scene. I tried to load the model in (https://threejs.org/editor/), but, failed.

How can i fix this??? please help..

The file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckC1qiIRGDskO240Y5N7oIBJufocEiTb/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It all works fine. Your 3d Model is simply to big. Change the scale in THREE.js to 0.001 or change the size of the model in an editor like blender. Also add a light source of some sort. Otherwise it will be all black.

[image]